# Differentially closed fields

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, differential-operators, noncommutative-rings, differential-algebra

Let F be a field. Recall that an additive map $d: F\rightarrow F$ is said to be a derivation if $d(ab)=ad(b)+d(a)b$.

Now let $F$ be a ring and let $d$ be a derivation of $F$. Examples I have in mind is $F=\mathbb{C}((t))$, $F=\mathbb{C}(t)$, $F=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, or more generally field of rational functions on some space. In these cases, the derivation is given by differentiating with respect to one of the variables. Note that we count $d=0$ as a derivation as well.

The ring of $d$-polynomials $F_d\{T\}$ is the ring which is equal to the usual polynomial ring as an additive group but where multiplication is modified by
$$
Ta=aT + d(a), \quad \quad \forall\, a\in F.
$$

Now let me introduce a definition:

Definition: $F$ is said to be $d$-closed if every polynomial in $F_d\{T\}$ can be factored into linear factors over $F$. $F$ is said to be naively differentially closed if it is $d$-closed for every derivation $d$. (Or maybe for a reasonable subset of all derivations).

I have used the word naive because it looks like this is different from the accepted definition of differentially closed field, cf. http://library.msri.org/books/Book39/files/dcf.pdf. I'd be grateful if somebody explains why the accepted definition of differentially closed field is more reasonable than the one given here.

Example: I believe the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}((t))$ is differentially closed (in the naive sense), where the relevant derivations are the ones which are continuous with respect to the $t$-adic topology. I don't know of other examples.

I'm interested to see what can be done with with the above definition. For instance, is it true that every field has a canonically defined unique field extension which is differentially closed (in the naive sense)?

Perhaps throughout I should assume that $F$ (and/or its field of constants) have characteristic zero, although it would be interesting to see how much goes through in positive characteristics.

Comment: probably you should add the tag model theory